# skyscanner query string url

Tags: query-string, querystringparameter, skyscanner

Generate a skyscanner url by passing two pieces of data as a query string with FROM and TO locations, so that the skyscanner search is already filled in when the user lands on the site from my url

This is what I expect, is it possible?

https://www.skyscanner.it/?FROM=AKL&TO=HNL